# How can i update asset path in Yii1?

Tags: php, yii1.x

Currently asset render with path

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/b9cee958/pager.css
```

but, I want to render asset using the controller action, e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/renderAsset?id=/b9cee958/pager.css
```

Where in ManagerController, i have action RenderAsset where actually want to give the base path.

How can i do that ??